# Install software remotely

Tags: powershell

The problem is that the command wont execute, do you see anything wrong with this command. I've copied the file to the remote server first then trying to run this command.

```
Invoke-Command -computername $server -scriptblock {c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe -ArgumentList "c:\Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu /upgrade /quiet /norestart" -Wait -PassThru -Verbose}
```

Comment: Looking this, it has to be something really stupid I'm missing.

Comment: Sounds stupid, but have you tried it without quotes for the ArgumetnList

Comment: **.msu** installations would not work remotely, that is how the security is ....as far as i've researched. You may get events logged for installation but it won't be installed. I'll be watching this post if there is a way out of it.

Comment: I found that installing windows updates remotely is not supported. I plan to create a cmd on the remote machine that contains the commands. Then use PS to call that .cmd

Comment: The above didnt work. Are there any ideas on how to accomplish this. I'm just trying to install the update that contains Powershell 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start-Process -Filepath 'c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe' -Arg....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get some of the servers and desktops upgraded to powershell 5. I've tried using powershell to install framework 5 but after a few hours of it failing I found an article that says MS does not support this. Do you know of a way to install PS 5 without SCCM or without going machine to machine?

Comment: Still nothing, Any suggestions out there?